# borrar ciertas partes de un texto texto en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

digamos que tengo varios divs que contienen un texto ejemplo

`<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel ante diam. Donec vitae magna metus. Curabitur at lorem non augue mollis molestie. Nam augue nisi, dignissim a nunc nec, placerat tempor nisi. Donec rutrum eros in urna tristique, quis vehicula risus rutrum. Duis quis arcu id tortor faucibus euismod non quis sem. Sed vulputate dui vitae rutrum tempus. Vivamus eu diam lacus. Aliquam convallis luctus convallis. Vestibulum et sapien nisl.
</div>`

como podría eliminar con javascript solo el texto que esta antes del primer punto?

Answer (score 7):

Quizás podrías tomar el índice del primer `.` usando `javascript`, por ejemplo:

```js
/* Ahora con 'javascript', quitamos el texto que está antes del punto, incluído el punto. */

function cambiar_texto() {
    var mi_div = document.getElementById("mi_texto"),
           indice;
    indice = mi_div.textContent.indexOf('.');
    mi_div.textContent = mi_div.textContent.substring(indice + 1);
}
```

```html
  
    <!-- Tu `HTML`: -->
    <!-- Le añadimos un identificador al div -->
    <div id="mi_texto"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel ante diam. Donec vitae magna metus. Curabitur at lorem non augue mollis molestie. Nam augue nisi, dignissim a nunc nec, placerat tempor nisi. Donec rutrum eros in urna tristique, quis vehicula risus rutrum. Duis quis arcu id tortor faucibus euismod non quis sem. Sed vulputate dui vitae rutrum tempus. Vivamus eu diam lacus. Aliquam convallis luctus convallis. Vestibulum et sapien nisl. </div>

<input type="button" value="Cambiar texto" onclick="cambiar_texto();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `str.split(".").splice(1).join()` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <body>

      <div id="div_texto">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel ante diam. Donec vitae magna metus. Curabitur at lorem non augue mollis molestie. Nam augue nisi, dignissim a nunc nec, placerat tempor nisi. Donec rutrum eros in urna tristique, quis vehicula risus rutrum. Duis quis arcu id tortor faucibus euismod non quis sem. Sed vulputate dui vitae rutrum tempus. Vivamus eu diam lacus. Aliquam convallis luctus convallis. Vestibulum et sapien nisl.
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = document.getElementById("div_texto").textContent;
var strArray = str.split(".").splice(1).join();
document.getElementById("div_texto").textContent = strArray;

</script>

    </body>
</head>
</html>
```